# blobStoreService.serve() is not giving download file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a servlet in which I first download a pdf in from http://www.cbwe.gov.in/htmleditor1/pdf/sample.pdf upload it's content on my blobstore and when a user sends a get request in browser a blob will be downloaded in browser, but instead of downloading it's showing data in some other format. Here is my code of servlet:

```
package org.ritesh;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.files.AppEngineFile;
import com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.files.FileService;
import com.google.appengine.api.files.FileWriteChannel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlobURLServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");

         FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

          // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"

          String url="http://www.cbwe.gov.in/htmleditor1/pdf/sample.pdf";
          URL url1=new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
          String content_type=conn.getContentType();
          InputStream stream =conn.getInputStream();
          AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/pdf");
          file=new AppEngineFile(file.getFullPath());
         Boolean lock = true;
          FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

          // This time we write to the channel directly
          String s1="";
          String s2="";

          byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);


          writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
          writeChannel.closeFinally();
          BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
          BlobstoreService blobStoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
          blobStoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);


    }
}
```

I deploy this servlet on onemoredemo1.appspot.com. Please open this url and notice when u click on BlobURL servlet it's showing content instead of showing downloading dialog. What modification should I do in my code so it shows download dialog in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
```

You've said that the content is plain text, when it's not. You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header appropriately as an attachment, and set the content type to `application/pdf`.

Additionally, if you're going to serve binary content, you shouldn't *also* use the writer (which you're writing `"Hello, world"` with).

If you change your first couple of lines to:

```
resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.pdf");
```

you may find that's all that's required.